# Create then deploy war from git

Tags: java, war, wildfly

So Im kinda new to this things so I do not know alot about it.
We have a wildfly server running in school and the only way to access it is by ssh.

I know how to create war using eclipse (export as war) and put it in wildfly deployments folder - that works.
Since I cannot to that all the time, we would like to automatize this. The source is on git so I would like it to pull - then create war - move it in deployments folder.

I tried using command

```
jar cvf name.war folder_of_code
```

But that did not work, when I try to access the site I get error 403 forbidden (even tho deploy was successful)
Now when I looked at war, I saw there were no .classes files inside, so I thought that is the problem.

But I'm stuck at what else to do. Any advise would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use build tools such as maven or gradle.

Here is an example maven pom.xml file that will build Your project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company.your</groupId>
  <artifactId>SampleWebApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name> SampleWebApp </name>
  <url>http://your.company.com</url>
</project>
```

Put this file in root directory of your project. Your source code should be placed in src/main/java subdirectory and static content in src/main/webapp